# Is there a way to remove the date and time from wingpanel in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, time

[image: remove date and time]

All I want to do is hide the date and time from the center of wingpanel, I circled the location of the date and time for reference. I don't think it looks ugly or anything I just don't feel the need to have it displayed. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the indicator

> sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-datetime

revert it with

> sudo apt-get install wingpanel-indicator-datetime

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was using dconf-editor. Just install it and is very simple to configure. I followed this tutorial [Elementary OS customization](https://petermolnar.net/elementaryos-customize-date-time-in-wingpanel/)